# Assign variable in JavaScript always null

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list that is repeated 30 times on a page. I have created a function that should take care of the `value`, but every time I step through in the browser the variable is always `null`.

I am calling my `select` like this:`onchange="showDropDown(capability_4_1_b,this.value)"`

my function:

```
function showDropDown(id,value) {
var nc = document.getElementById(id);
  if (value === "NC" || value === "OBS") {
      nc.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      nc.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

The div I am targeting is `<div id="capability_4_1_b" style="display:none;">`

I have looked in the source and the element is in the `DOM` my JS files are at the bottom of the page.
[image: Developer tools]

The function above is how I started doing the `functions` but I want to achieve this with one function. The functions work but too much repetition :).

Comment: as you can see on the right side, `id` is already a DOM element.

Comment: You're missing quotes around `capability_4_1_b` in your call to `showDropDown()` -- if it's an id, it should be a string.

Comment: Thanks Guys  always the simplest of things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass an actual string:

```
onchange="showDropDown('capability_4_1_b', this.value)"
                       ^                ^
```

Otherwise, you're actually [passing the element itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1048572), that's the reason why you don't get an error.

Answer (score 2):

`capability_4_1_b` is a variable. The browser is resolving it into an Element object. The JavaScript is then converting it to a string and then trying to find an element with an ID that matches it.

You need to pass a string instead.

```
onchange="showDropDown(&quot;capability_4_1_b&quot;,this.value)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onchange="showDropDown(capability_4_1_b,this.value)"
```

You didn't quote `capability_4_1_b`, so it's not working.

```
onchange="showDropDown('capability_4_1_b',this.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your onchange method call from

**onchange="showDropDown(capability_4_1_b,this.value)"**

To

**onchange='showDropDown("capability_4_1_b",this.value)'**

You are passing the id which should be in string format so need to write in double quotes.